# How to load .class files from an .jar that are in an package

Tags: java, classloader, urlclassloader

I need to load the Client.class using an ClassLoader .

[image: Packaging Structure]

When I use this code:

```
 ClassLoader clientClassLoader = new URLClassLoader(
                new URL[] { new File("client.jar").toURL() });
        Class<?> clientClass = clientClassLoader.loadClass("pkhonor.Client");
```

I'm getting java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: /pkhonor/Client.
How should i Fix this problem?

Comment: Can check that File("client.jar") exists?

Comment: Is the URL correct for the jar file?

Comment: Make sure that the file exists

Comment: The issue is definitely how you're instantiating the classloader. As others have said, check the path of your client.jar file: it doesn't look right to me.

Comment: The jar file is null , thanks for clearing that up.